# width of the MUI DataGrid becoming larger than the parent space and stretching its size

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

I'm making an app with a sidebar that can be increased or decreased, and I'm having a problem. By decreasing the sidebar, the DataGrid obviously increases its size. But when I increase it, instead of decreasing its size, the DataGrid remains large.

[Video demonstrating the error (Imgur)](https://imgur.com/a/1GJB8BA)

The sidebar follows the logic of the [Mini Variant Drawer](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-drawer/#mini-variant-drawer)

in short, this is the total code of the page, from the root layout

```
  <Box
    sx={{
      display: "flex",
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%",
      bgcolor: "background.paper",
      paddingTop: 10,
    }}
  >
    {/* <Navigation /> */}
    {/* Navigation component */}
    <Topbar toggleDrawer={() => setOpen((o) => !o)} />
    <Sidebar open={open} close={() => setOpen(false)} />
    {/* Navigation component */}
    <Box
      component="main"
      sx={{
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        bgcolor: "background.default",
        paddingBottom: 5,
        borderRadius: "8px 0 0 0",
        "@media(max-width:600px)": {
          borderRadius: 0,
        },
      }}
    >
      {/* the page */}
      <Box paddingX={2.5} width="100%">
        <Paper sx={{ padding: 4, paddingBottom: 0 }} elevation={0}>
          <Box width="100%" paddingY={4} height="625px">
            {/* <FinanceiroDataGrid data={data || []} mutate={() => mutate()} /> */}
            {/* DataGrid component */}
              <Box sx={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}>
                <DataGrid
                  columns={columns}
                  rows={rows}
                  slots={{ noRowsOverlay: NoRows }}
                />
              </Box>
            {/* DataGrid component */}
          </Box>
        </Paper>
      </Box>
      {/* the page */}
    </Box>
  </Box>
```

and this is the column code (if that makes any difference)

```
const columns: GridColDef[] = useMemo(
() => [
  {
    field: "efetuado",
    headerName: "Efetado",
    editable: false,
    width: 120,
    type: "boolean",
    renderCell: (cell) => (
      <ChipEfetuado efetuado={cell.value} entrada={cell.row.valor >= 0} />
    ),
  },
  {
    field: "data",
    headerName: "Data",
    editable: false,
    width: 100,
    type: "date",
    renderCell: (cell) => (
      <Chip
        label={`${cell.value.getDate()} de ${meses[
          cell.value.getMonth()
        ].substring(0, 3)}`}
        size="small"
      />
    ),
  },
  {
    field: "valor",
    headerName: "Valor",
    editable: false,
    width: 120,
    type: "number",
    renderCell: (cell) =>
      `${cell.value < 0 ? "- " : ""}${formatarDinheiro(cell.value)}`,
  },
  {
    field: "nome",
    headerName: "Nome",
    sortable: false,
    editable: false,
    hideable: false,
    flex: 1,
    renderCell: (cell) => (
      <Tooltip
        title={<Typography fontSize={12}>{cell.value}</Typography>}
        placement="bottom-start"
        arrow
      >
        {cell.value}
      </Tooltip>
    ),
  },
  {
    field: "remetente",
    headerName: "Agente",
    editable: false,
    flex: 1,
    renderCell: (cell) => (
      <Tooltip
        title={<Typography fontSize={12}>{cell.value}</Typography>}
        placement="bottom-start"
        arrow
      >
        {cell.value}
      </Tooltip>
    ),
  },

  {
    field: "forma",
    headerName: "Forma",
    editable: false,
    width: 100,
    renderCell: (cell) => (
      <Tooltip
        title={<Typography fontSize={12}>{cell.value}</Typography>}
        placement="bottom-start"
        arrow
      >
        {cell.value}
      </Tooltip>
    ),
  },
  {
    field: "descricao",
    headerName: "Descrição",
    sortable: false,
    editable: false,
    width: 335,
    renderCell: (cell) => (
      <Tooltip
        title={<Typography fontSize={12}>{cell.value}</Typography>}
        placement="bottom-start"
        arrow
      >
        {cell.value}
      </Tooltip>
    ),
  },
  {
    field: "Ações",
    type: "actions",
    width: 100,
    sortable: false,
    hideable: false,
    getActions: (params) => [
      <EditButton key={params.id} id={params.id} />,
      <DeleteButton key={params.id} onClick={() => setDialog(params.id)} />,
    ],
  },
],
[]
```

);

Comment: I have this exact same issue, did you find a solution?